# matplotlib: add line to axes, such that ax.set_axis_off() also hides line

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to add a line to the axes themselves, such that when I hide the axes, the line is also hidden?

For example, the following code creates a plot, and then draws a dashed vertical line on the axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot([-1,1], [-1,1])
dashed_line = Line2D([0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, 1.0], linestyle = '--', linewidth = 1, color = [0,0,0], zorder = 1, transform = ax.transData)
ax.lines.append(dashed_line)
fig.savefig('Plot_with_axes.png')
```

[image]

Now, I hide the axes.

```
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.savefig('Plot_without_axes.png')
```

[image]

The dashed vertical line remains.  How do I make the dashed vertical line be hidden at the same time as I hide the axes?

Note: I realize that I can do `dashed_line.set_visible(False)`, but that gets annoying to do for each thing I add to the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when running `ax.set_axis_off()` in your example above, matplotlib doesn't have a way to differentiate between the line you added via `ax.lines.append()` and the one added via `ax.plot()`.

To have the vertical line recognized as part of the axis, you could add it as an extra spine:

```
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.path import Path

ax.spines[u'middle'] = Spine( ax, 'right', Path(([[ 0., -1.], [ 0.,  1.]]), None), linestyle='--', linewidth=1, facecolor=[0,0,0], zorder=1, transform = ax.transData )
```

This will have the intended effect when setting the axis off:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason the z-order in `Spine(..., zorder = 1, ...)` got ignored so the dashed spine was on top of the blue line.  Once I added `ax.spines[u'middle'].set_zorder(1)`, the dashed spine went below the blue line as desired.